# Tomcat6 and JRE7 compatibility issue. Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I have a web app compiled with JRE7 and now i'd like to run it on Tomcat6. When I launch my app I see exception in the logs:

```
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
```

This exception comes from the class that implements ServletContextListener.

Does that mean I have to use Tomcat7 for code compiled with JRE7? Is there a workaround? Any information will be valuable.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592791/tomcat6-and-java-7

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you forgot to vote to close

Comment: It has nothing to do with Tomcat6. It's that you're attempting to run Java 7 bytecode with a Java 6 JVM. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're attempting to run Java 7 bytecode with a Java 6. You need to deploy it to Tomcat 7 or recompile using JDK 1.6. Check what JRE your Tomcat uses. I guess it's Java 6 JVM.

Comment: You are completely right, my catalina.sh file in JAVA_HOME had reference to 1.6 JDK. 
Thanks fo help!

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the server information through its status page:

{running-tomcat-url}/manager/status

On that page you can see the version of Java on which your Tomcat runs