# Tomcat doesn't start when updating Java from 5 to Java 7

Tags: tomcat6, java-7

My project was compiled with Java 5 and running in Tomcat 6.
I moved to Java 7.
and when I try to start Tomcat 6, it doesn't start, what can be the cause?
Does tomcat6 support jdk 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are not the one that encounter errors while running Tomcat7 with Java7:

[Tomcat6 and Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592791/tomcat6-and-java-7)